# How realistic are the drone live feed in Homeland

Tags: realism, homeland

I'm currently watching Homeland season 4, a TV show taking place in Pakistan. The  U.S. intelligence services and army forces make heavy use of drone imagery in the series, with huge consequences on the plot. The images are often good enough (resolution, sharpness etc) to recognize faces of characters!

It really looks to me as far fetched, but I must say I have little insight into what is technologically possible, hence the question: to what extend are those drones images realistic?